# Convert a value to an integer

Tags: python, integer

Here are the directions to the homework problem:

Define a function called `get_integer_value` that takes one parameter called `prompt_text` and returns a number of type integer.

The function must meet the following requirements:

1. Prompt the user using the parameter variable as the text to prompt the user storing it in
   a variable called input_value .
2. Write and if\else-statement to verify that the inputted value is a number before converting it. Use the condition `input_value.isdigit()` .
3. if the condition is true then:
4. Convert the value to an integer.
5. Return the variable holding the coefficient value.
6. Otherwise\ else
7. Print the message "[variable] is not a valid integer. The program will now
   terminate." Where [variable] is the `input_value` .
8. Exit the program by typing the code: `sys.exit(-1)` .

By testing the input before converting the value to an integer, we avoid a runtime error that causes our program to crash. Having a program crash with red text scares users and will not instill confidence in your programs. It is better that you control how the program handles unexpected errors during runtime.

It should come out like the example below:

```
Input a: 3
The type of a is <class 'int'>
```

This is what I typed so far in Python:

```
def get_integer_value(prompt_text):
    input_value = input("Input a: ")
```

So I am stuck and don't know how to go on from here. Can someone guide me or help me with this please?

Comment: Now do Step 2 in the list of directions.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
import sys

input_value = input('Input a:')
if input_value.isdigit():
    result = int(input_value)
    print(result)
else:
    print('[variable] is not a valid integer. The program will now terminate.')
    sys.exit(-1)
```